# llvm-nm giving error on Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures

Tags: bash, llvm, symbols, nm

I am using llvm-nm(nm) to view the symbols in a binary.  I am trying to view a file that is a Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures: [x86_64:current ar archive] [arm64], however when I run the command `nm ./my_library.a` it fails with response code 1 and message `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/nm: error: ./my_library.a: Invalid argument.`.

I have seen other people view the symbol table without issue using the same command, same file, and the same version of nm (Apple LLVM version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)).  I don't see any place to increase nm's verbosity of error messages.  Any ideas for how I might go about debugging this issue?

Comment: Retry the command without the `./` before `my_library.a`

Comment: @droptop I have tried it with full and relative paths, same error.

Comment: Then there should be a problem with your archive